# php error al enviar los datos de un formulario

Tags: php, mysql, formularios

Estoy estudiando programacion web y me han pedido crear un formulario basico el cual contenga algunas restricciones, lo cual segun yo hice correctamente, pero, no guarda la informacion, este es el codigo:

```
<?php
session_start();
$error = "";
if (array_key_exists("Logout", $_GET)) {
//viene de la pagina sesionIniciada
session_unset();
setcookie('id', '', time()-60*60);
$_COOKIE['id'] ="";


} else if ((array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION) AND $_SESSION['id']) OR (array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE) AND $_COOKIE['id'])) {
header("Location: sessionIniciada.php");
}
 if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) {
$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id8683745_sansa", "as102030", "id8683745_usuarios");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Hubo algun error en la conexion con la base de datos");
}
if (!$_POST['email']) {
    $error .= "<br> Email requerido";
}
if (!$_POST['password']) {
    $error .= "<br> Contraseña requerida";
}
if ($error != "") {
    $error = "<p>Hubo algun errores en el formulario: ".$error."</p>";
} else {
    $query="select id from usuarios where email ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace, $_POST['email'])."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($enlace, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $error="Email ya registrardo, favor intentarlo con otro";
    } else {
        $query = "insert into usuarios (email,password) values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace, $_POST['email'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($enlace, $_POST['password'])."') ";
        if (!mysqli_query($enlace, $query)) {
            $error ="<p>No hemos podido completar el registro, favor intentarlo mas tarde</p>";
        } else {
            //actualizar el almacenamiento del password
            $query = "update usuarios set password= '".md5(md5(mysqli_insert_id($enlace)).$_POST['password'])."' where id =".mysqli_insert_id($enlace);
            mysqli_query($enlace, $query);
            $_SESSION['id']=mysqli_insert_id($enlace);
            if ($_POST['iniciado']==1) {
                setcookie('id', mysqli_insert_id($enlace), time()+60*60*24*365);
            }
            header("Location: sessionIniciada.php");
        }
    }
}
  }

 ?>

<div id="error">
<?php echo $error; ?>
</div>

<form method="POST">

<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="tu email aqui">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="tu contraseña aqui">
<input type="checkbox" name="iniciado" value=0>
<input type="submit" value="Registrarte" name="submit">

 </form>
```

El problema creo que esta en este if

```
 if (!mysqli_query($enlace, $query)) {
            $error ="<p>No hemos podido completar el registro, favor intentarlo mas tarde</p>";
```

ese es el mensaje de error que me sale al intentar enviar los datos: No hemos podido completar el registro, favor intentarlo mas tarde

la variable $enlace incluso la copie de otro ejemplo que hice totalmente funcional, entonces el problema estaria en la variable $query, pero, la comparo con el otro ejemplo que hice y no he podido dar con algun tipo de error, al menos para mi.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Agrega el error de `mysqli` al mensaje, poniendo esto: **`$error ="<p>No hemos podido completar el registro, favor intentarlo mas tarde</p><p>El error es: ".mysqli_error($enlace)."</p>";`** y dinos qué muestra en ese caso... Para luego, considera optimizar el código. Es demasiado *verbose*, hay cosas que se pueden evitar o evaluar en conjunto, evitando tantos `if`. Si aprendes el estilo orientado a objetos, ganas en claridad de código. Pero dado que puede ser un curso, no sé si eso sobrepase las exigencias del mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta, voy a hacerlo ahora mismo

Comment: muchisimas gracias a todos, ya pude resolver el problema, con mysqli_error() me salio cual era exactamente el problema, me salio que tenia una columna en la base de datos que no la estaba llenando con el formulario y no tenia como default null, es una funcion maravillosa xD, muchas gracias a todos. Por otro lado, A. Cedano como harias mi codigo mas optimo, para asi tener una idea de como hacerlo mas adelante

Answer (score -1):

El problema no creo que esté en el IF, si no más bien en la consulta, por alguna razón no te está haciendo el INSERT en la base de datos, puedes capturar el error con mysqli_error

```php
if (!mysqli_query($enlace, $query)) {
            $error ="<p>Hubo un error insertando al usuario: ". mysqli_error( $enlace )
." </p>";
```

De esta forma capturas el error en la consulta y podrás solucionarlo o podremos ayudarte a solucionarlo.